# get fd from file pointer in kernel space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, file-permissions, kernel

Given a struct file, is it possible to get the associated file descriptor in linux kernel space? I am trying to change permissions using either sys_chmod or sys_fchmod. One takes a file descriptor the other expects a filename from user space. I can figure out how to get the filename but how would I cast it to a user space pointer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're after is `chmod_common`:

```
static int chmod_common(struct path *path, umode_t mode)
```

Which takes a `path` and the mode you want to set. Unfortunately, as you noticed, **it's static** and obviously not exported. So you could go multiple ways:

- Replicate whatever it does in a function of your own
- Get "the file descriptor" from `struct file` (ugly)
- Find a way to call `sys_chmod`

Now `sys_chmod` expects a user pointer but you're in the kernel. Here's what you could do to trick it:

```
mm_segment_t oldfs = get_fs();

char __user *userptr;
userptr = (char __user __force *) kernptr;

set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

/* call sys_chmod */

set_fs(oldfs);
```

All this is very much in line with ["things you never should do in the Kernel"](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8110/print).

Comment: Thank you! I knew that an alternative was the ugly traversing of a task's fdtable but I never knew of __force.