# Getting socket ID of socket in sk_buff

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel

is it possible to obtain socket `ID` in linux kernel in `sk_buff` struct?
I know i could get `socket` using this code:

```
const struct tcphdr *th = tcp_hdr(skb);
struct sock *sk = __inet_lookup_skb(&tcp_hashinfo, skb, th->source, th->dest);
if (sk)
    struct socket* = sk->sk_socket;
```

Where could i find ID and what maximum value of this id?

Answer (score 0):

A socket is a file.

You'll find, inside the `struct socket`, a `struct file *file` member.

I recommend you to [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913965/get-fd-from-file-pointer-in-kernel-space), specifically the link ["things you never should do in the Kernel"](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8110/print) on the accepted answer, because I'm worried about the reason why you're trying to retrieve the file descriptor from a socket structure in the kernel (usually, you want to do the exact opposite).

To retrieve the file descriptor from a given file under the kernel, you'll need to iterate the `fdtable` (search for `files_fdtable()`)... this is a tremendous amount of work to do, specially if there is a huge amount of open files.

The maximum value for a file descriptor value will be the maximum number of files allowed in the system, and can be retrieved with something like:

```
files_fdtable(current->files)->max_fds;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I need some king of connection ID because i need to create static array with pointers to my data for each connection. When i was in usermode(hooking `send`, `write` and etc.) i created static array with size `array[65536]`, because socket descriptor is `short` and when i need to get data from this array for example in `send` function i used `array[fd]` - it is very fast and safe and now i'm searching for alternative for my kernel netfilter module

Comment: Note that `socket()` returns a `int` (not a `short`) and you should not make assumptions regarding its size without effectively check its size. On my system where I'm writing this comment, a `int` is 32-bit long, meaning that your array should have been declared as `int array[2147483648]`, obviously causing a stack overflow, because you would be trying to allocate 8GiB on the stack. My point is, you probably want to change your approach. I recommend you to check out the netfilter modules code in the `net/netfilter/` directory and check how they might be handling situations like yours.

Comment: Hi, i found one thing, it is `sk_buff->sock->sk_user_data`, i could paste here pointer to my data, but there is a problem, on server side(where i load my driver) every client connections connects to one server port, and `sk_buff->sock` is same for every client connection, maybe you know where i could find `custom data` for every connection, where i cound paste pointer to my data?

Comment: I think you're talking about the bound SOCK_STREAM socket that `listen()`'s, not the socket that is installed for the `accept()`, which is specific of a particular [client] stream.

Comment: yes, on server side(where i load my kernel module) server socket which uses `accept`, and all `sk_buff` coming to this ports has the same `sk_buff->sock->sk_user_data`, for every connection to this port. Do you know where in kernel i could store my private data for every tcp connection?

Comment: I unable to answer that question without checking the current kernel code and see how exactly that kind of handling is preformed. Probably you should ask a new question as there may be other users that may accurately answer you. Sorry.